# Registering consumer and handlers in Masstransit 3

Tags: masstransit

I am trying to register consumers and handlers in Masstransit 3, but i cant use the IMessageConsumer interface. How can i make MT3 use an interface of e.g. IHandle<> to recieve messages?

Comment: Did you see the examples in the GitHub issue to wire this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .Handler() to wire up your handlers. There are no dependencies needed to use a handler. You'll likely want to create an extension method to register your own handler in a way that allows you to manage the lifecycle of your handlers since there is no built-in lifecycle management when using handlers (in comparison to consumers anyway).